# jquery dialog form with dynamic variables

Tags: jquery, dialog

Currently I have an html form - which I call with jquery dialog - to insert new records into a table. But I also would like to update existing records with the same form - using jquery dialog. I'm not sure within the dialog how I access these data values - or pass them in as arguments - and hook them up with the form elements...? Anyone has done this before and knows an agile technique to do this? 
kind regards, Patrick

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery UI dialog then you can access any element in the page as if it is not a dialog. Jquery UI dialog makes a div a dialog by making it invisible ("display:none"), adds the proper widget items and shows it when u call dialog("open"). So you can access any element in the page since it is just a div in your page.

HTH